# Recursion too deep error on reset-ticks

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to place plotting procedures within the code so that I can flip a switch to determine if plots will be graphed. Strangely, I am getting a "recursion to deep error" (see screen shot at bottom). I only get this error when my show-plots? switch is true. Below is the relevant code:

```
to setup
;many non relevant setup procedures
reset-ticks
end

to go
;many non relevant go procedures
if show-plots? = true [plot-data]

to plot-data
  let input-list (list "MS" "IC" "GF" "S" "R" "Ri" "DC")
  let reporter-list (list Mech_stim Intra-IC Intra-GF cell-energy GLUT hunger Death-Prob)
set-current-plot "Intracellular Network"
(foreach input-list reporter-list [set-current-plot-pen ?1 plotxy T_hrs ?2])
end
```

I have tried to use this plotting procedure with lists to save on the typing the same thing over and over, because I have many plots to update.

I find it very strange that my code within the `go` procedure is determining when I get the "recursion too deep error" for something in the `setup`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how it can be fixed? Thx.[image]

Comment: "I find it very strange that my code within the go procedure is determining when I get the "recursion too deep error" for something in the setup" — that would indeed be exceedingly strange. Are you certain that you have ruled out other possible explanations? How?

Comment: @SethTisue The error only began immediately after I coded the method for `plot-data` within the code. The error also only occurs when the switch "show-plots?" is on. Finally, if I put "show-plots? to off during the setup, and then switch it on after the setup procedures have run, then I get the same "recession too deep" error called on `tick` during the first tick. It seems the problem must be with the way I coded the `plot-data` procedure. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I really followed all that, but... does your plot have code inside it? is `plot-data` called from inside the plot itself? `reset-ticks` in setup causes the code in a plot to run.

Comment: @SethTisue, You have helped me to locate the problem. In the section of "plot setup commands" of another plot, I had a piece of code saying:  "if show-plots? = true [plot-data]. This piece of code was remaining from when I (unsuccessfully) tried use this section to determine if plot-data would be ran. Once I have deleted this piece of code, no more errors. Thanks for your help in finding this trouble causing remnant of code.